# UIView's CALayer not always released when UIView is released

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, memory-management

I'm currently investigating various memory issues using Instruments and in the process noticed that if I print the description of a UIView to the debug log you can see the CALayer's memory address that is backing that UIView.

After the UIView is released (i.e. UIViewController released) I paused execution and attempted to PO on the UIView's memory address and I got nil for all the ones I tested which is what I expected but some of the CALayers that were associated with the released UIViews when PO'ed still printed out live descriptions into the logger which basically means that they have not been released and are still in memory.

What would cause the CALayer not to be released when the parent UIView is released, is this some kind of caching mechanism, bug or leak.

It's worth noting I'm using iOS7 and ARC.

Example:

**PO of UIView before releasing UIViewController:**

```
Printing description of self->_reviewsContainerView:
<UIView: 0xefb4dc0; frame = (0 466; 229 554); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xefdfb30>>
```

**PO of CALayer 0xefdfb30:**

```
po 0xefdfb30 <CALayer:0xefdfb30; position = CGPoint (114.5
743); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 229 554); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; >
```

Comment: have you checked the CALayer's `-retainCount`?

Comment: [I don't think looking at the retain count is a very good solution](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/151883iA0DD1186C3E25FDB/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1). It can be [very misleading](http://whentouseretaincount.com).

Comment: Are you sure that the layers really wasn't released? It may be that the pointer to the layer just isn't automatically set to nil and that the memory at that location has changed yet.

Comment: I just checked one of the CALayer's and it had a retainCount of 1

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I've updated my question to show the debugger output. So are you saying that even when something is released it can't still hang around in memory?

Comment: Unless I'm really remembering things wrong or things have changed in recent days. The memory is marked as free but it's not zeroed out. And unless the pointer is weak, it will still point to the old memory.

Comment: Ah I see, that would explain it then, so it's a bit of a false positive printing out memory addresses. That's helpful.